# Auto selection of some values of Checkbox group in Lotus Xpages

Tags: checkbox, xpages-ssjs

I am using a checkbox group whose values are populated from the back end configuration . The checkbox group is for selection of Lab parameters . In the configuration , I kept status of some parameter's as disabled and some parameters are enabled (with the usage of status field ). checkbox group brings all the disabled and enabled lab parameters . By default , I want the auto selection of those Lab parameters that are set as enabled i.e enabled parameters are auto selected in checkbox group. Is there any way to have some checked ( auto selected) values in the checkbox group .

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of the checkbox in the data properties:

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1">
    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:new Array("TestValue1","TestValue2")}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Test Label1"
        itemValue="TestValue1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Test Label2"
        itemValue="TestValue2">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Test Label3"
        itemValue="TestValue3">
    </xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

I have used an array, but you can use any function that returns an array to do this.